# how often optimize table query called

Tags: mysql

Actually i queried optimize table query for one table. then i didn't do any operation on that table. then again i'm querying optimize table query at the end of every month. but the data in the table may be changed once in four or 8 months. is it create any problem in performance of the mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't do `DML` operations on the table, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is useless.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` cleans the table of deleted records, sorts the index pages (brings the physical order of the pages in consistence to logical one) and recalculates the statistics.

For the duration of the command, the table is unavailable both for reading and writing, and the command may take long for large tables.

Answer (score 1):

Did your read [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) about [`OPTIMIZE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html)? And do you have a problem you want to solve using `OPTIMIZE`? If not, don't use this statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't quite change over a period of 4-8 months it should not create any issue with performance for the end of month report. 
However if the count of rows that are changed in the 4-8 months period is huge then you would want to rebuild indexes/analyze the tables so that the queries run fine after the load.